# Problem with Rotating Activity Clockwise On Real Device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, screen-orientation

I Have an Activity , that has a button on it , i want to change orientation 90 degrees clockwise after everytime user clicks on button , i wrote some codes and worked on emulator , but when i tested it on real device , its not worked perfect , 
and when my code get to the case 1 it back to the PORTRAIT mode instead of changing rotation to  REVERSE_PORTRAIT

Here is MyCode :

```
btnchangeRotation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            Log.v("rotation--", ""+rotation);

            switch (rotation) {

                case 0:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Also I Added Permision To Manifest Like This :

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Note That It works on Emulator Completely Without Problem .
Any Suggestions Will Be Helpful .
Thanks To Any Suggestions .

Note : 
When I Turn on Screen Rotation On Real Device , It Works Very Well , 
But When I Turn It Off , It Is Just set to Portrait and Landscape , 
I Want To Do It With Devices Without Gyroscop Sensor .

Comment: Have you tried debugging the real device and seeing what the rotation parameter value is?

Comment: Yes I Checked , values are correct , the app works on emulator and dont work with real device .

Answer (score 0):

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Maybe you mean:

```
MyActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The version you have is just calling a method and has no handle on the Activity itself.

Comment: There is No Problem with that , because it works with emulator , but did not work with real device .